# Small workgroup printer for five users connecting by Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, printer

Seeking a small workgroup printer (monochrome OK) where five users can print less than 50 plain paper pages (8.5"x11") a day from Windows 10. For security reasons, WiFi and wired LAN are out. Can't due the Bluetooth Low Energy/WiFi Direct combination either, which rules out a lot of HP printers. Is there a printer with integrated Bluetooth, or a Bluetooth print server, under a kilobuck, which will work with no, repeat no, WiFi?

Comment: Yes there are Bluetooth printers out there. If you would like a purchase recommendation for a Bluetooth printer it would greatly help if you listed your desired paper size (A3,A4,Legal ?), and upper price limit.

Answer (score 1):

### [HP Officejet 100 $356.99](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA9JA4KY3673)

[image]

- Rate: 22 ppm
- Resolution: 1200 dpi
- Connective technology: USB, **Bluetooth**
- Printer Technology: Colorized Thermal Inkjet
- Supported Paper Formats: **Letter (8.5" x 11")**, A 4/5/6, Legal, Executive, Statement, B5 (JIS)

This is the cheapest printer I could find that comes with bluetooth and wasn't one of those tiny consumer HP camera printers. As an addition note, it appears this printer is portable as it comes equipped with a Lithium ion battery. They also sell a [carrying case](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01K0XXB5C) for this printer if you feel the need to print something in the middle of a park or something.

Comment: This printer should work exactly like your average wireless printer, with the exception of its method of connectivity. In the [Office Jet 100's official documentation](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02666244) you add the printer exactly like a normal printer (Set up a Bluetooth wireless connection, Page 8).

Comment: @K7AAY I cannot find anything mentioning this limit in the [Official User Manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02648771), or [the product information page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-officejet-100-mobile-printer-series-l411/4231339/model/4231407/product-info). Trying asking Mark specifically "**How many users can add the printer in Windows and then add to its print queue?**". "Handle 3 users" is a bit vague. Otherwise I'll hunt for another printer and get back to you. There are some more expensive Laser based printers that are still under $1K.

Comment: Mark at HP chat support (session 4425047) says "It looks like the HP Officejet 100 Mobile Printer - L411a (CN551A) can handle up to 3 users only" so this is not a solution.  Also skip the HP OficeJet 250 Mobile CZ992A#B1H as it uses Bluetooth LE ('BLE') to make a link for WiFi Direct. Can't use WiFi, no way, no how.